# How use amsplain style with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, amsplain

Is it possible to use the `amsplain` bibliographic style with the `biblatex` package?

After processing the source file below, I get error: "Package biblatex Error: Style 'amsplain' not found."

```
%% source.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=amsplain]{biblatex}
\bibliography{referencesdb}

\begin{document}

Refer to \cite{thebook} for more information.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here's the `.bib` file used:

```
@book{
thebook,
author = {John Doe},
title = {The book without a Name},
publisher = {Mystery Books},
year = {2016},
}
```

The `amsplain.bst` file really is available in my TeXLive 2016 installation, because if I change the source to the following, then processing completes as expected.

```
%% source-no-biblatex.tex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Refer to \cite{thebook} for more information.

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{referencesdb}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't use `amsplain` with `biblatex`. `amsplain` is a `.bst` style and is thus used as you show in your second bit of code. `biblatex` needs `.bbx` and `.cbx` styles. Since there is no `amsplain.bbx` and no `amsplain.cbx` you can't use that style with `biblatex`.

Comment: So what files would I use with `biblatex` in order to recreate essentially the same `amsplain` style?

Comment: Why do you want to use `biblatex` if you have a style you can work with right now? AFAIK there is no `biblatex` implementation of `amsplain` so you would have to make do with `numeric` its derivatives or `trad-plain` of the `biblatex-trad` package. While `biblatex` has many superior features, you don't have to switch especially if you have a `.bst` style that works for you (it's unlikely you need the advanced features then).

Comment: See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) for a bit of background.

Comment: I had thought that `biblatex` would give more control with additional field types. I strongly prefer *most* aspects of the `amsplain` style -- especially no quote marks around titles -- but actually want the bibliography list itself to have the item numbers enclosed in brackets; is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Well, `biblatex` is often (for me at least) easier to modify than `.bst` styles. The question is: How much do you need that? And how far is the output you get from `style=numeric` in `biblatex` away from what you want to see? You can easily get rid of quotation marks around the titles, if that is all you need. But if you need much more, things might become a bit more involved.

Comment: I want *all*  aspects of `amsplain` style formatting of the references list -- except to put the numbers there in square brackets. (I am referring here to the actual printed bibliography; with `amsplain, already citations in the document will appear in square brackets.)

Comment: But how far off is it if you try `numeric`? That will tell you how much work you'd need to do (roughly) to customise the style according to your desiderata. If you want to include additional fields, you are already moving away from that style, of course. Part of what a style defines is what information, exactly, gets shown and what not.

Comment: Note that the answer to this is specific to you. It isn't just that you know what you want. You know what actually matters. If there's a difference in the way certain entry types are formatted, but you never use those types of sources, then it really doesn't matter how different they would be, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` uses a different style format than traditional BibTeX with its `.bst` files. (Arguably `biblatex`'s `.bbx`/`.cbx` files are easier to customise than `.bst` files.) You can't use `.bst` styles with `biblatex` and you can't use `biblatex` styles with traditional BibTeX. The two formats are incompatible and there is as of now no converter between the two formats (and it is unlikely there is ever going to be one).

So the answer to your question is *you can't*.

---

If you have a `.bst` file you like and you don't need any of `bibilatex`'s advanced features (of which there are many), you don't need to switch to `biblatex` - you can just go on using your `.bst` file with BibTeX.

If you do need to switch and still want to "retain your style", you should pick the closest match from the vast amount of [standard styles](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples) (which are easy to customise) or [custom styles](https://www.ctan.org/topic/biblatex) (which are *sometimes* much harder to customise - especially if they were tailor-made to follow some style guide) and modify it to your needs. Of course this is also a question of how flexible you are - what aspects of your old style do you want to retain, what are you not so fussed about?

There are few direct `biblatex` equivalents for `.bst` styles. Some `.bst` styles implement certain style guides/house styles and you might find a `biblatex` style that does the same - in that case though the output may differ in certain edge cases (because the standard isn't clear, has changed over time, or certain things weren't possible to implement, ...).

Comment: This is a serious deficiency of biblatex from the point of view of someone who is passing to using biblatex from using simply bibtex. Having to customize style files is precisely the sort of thing an end user wishes to completely avoid.