# Reference (\cite) in the title of a subsection and in pdf bookmark (hyperref) using bibtex instead of biblatex

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, citing, bookmarks, amsplain

My question is very similar to the one @leandriis asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390817/reference-cite-in-pdf-bookmark). I want to cite one of my references in the title of a subsection. Since I am using `hyperref` and the `\cite`-command causes trouble because such a tex-statement cannot be tranlated into a pdf-bookmark, I was using `\texorpdfstring` and put the `\cite`-command into the first argument. But what can I put into the second argument such that basically the same output appears in the resulting bookmark, just without `hyperref` in pdf-bookmark of course. I was thinking similar to @leandriis to somehow extract the number of the reference from the citation and write something like `[\getnumberfromcitation{nameofbibtexentry}, Theorem A]` into the second command. Yet, this seems impossible.

Then I found the question [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390817/reference-cite-in-pdf-bookmark). And there is a solution presented for `biblatex` which probably works. The problem is just that I am using `bibtex`, because I want to use the `bibliographystyle amsplain` which is apparently only available in `bibtex` (cf. this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329431/how-use-amsplain-style-with-biblatex)).

The question is: What can I do? How can I adapt the solution of @Ulrike Fischer in the question [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390817/reference-cite-in-pdf-bookmark) to the case of `bibtex` instead of `biblatex`? I am not enough of a tex-expert to answer this on my own. Thank you very much in advance for your help!

**Example of my tex-file.**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsthm, verbatim,amsmath,color,fancyhdr,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{turnstile} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

\def\tequiv{\ensuremath\sdststile{}{}}

\usepackage[letterpaper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,dvips]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection \texorpdfstring{{\normalfont(\cite[Subsection~x.y]{author})}}{What to write here?}}

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{lib}
%lib.bib has an entry with key author
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.  The first is solved in the linked post by Ulrike Fischer but using `biblatex` by patching the `\bibitem` commands to produce a `\label` that can be referenced.  This can also be done with standard `bibtex` as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@bibitem}{\ignorespaces}{\label{bib-#1}\ignorespaces}{}{}
\makeatother
```

(`\bibitem` calls `\@bibitem` if there is no optional argument, which is the case in your example, and the final macro executed by `\@bibitem` is `\ignorespaces`, we put our label just before that.)

You can then use `\ref{bib-author}` to the section title instead of `\cite{author}`.  You probably want to package this into a command `\mycite` to add square brackets.

```
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{[\ref{bib-#1}]}
```

The second problem is that you cannot use optional arguments in the pdf part of `\texorpdfstring`.  One thus needs to define a version of the citing command the takes required rather than optional arguments.

```
\newcommand{\myqcite}[2]{[\ref{bib-#2}, #1]}
```

Both these definitions assume you are citing only one item.
Now for use in titles you may as well hide away the `\texorpdfstring` in some helper commands so you can just write `\mytcite{author}` or `\mytqcite{Section X.Y}{author}`.

```
\newcommand{\mytcite}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\cite{#1}}{\mycite{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mytqcite}[2]{\texorpdfstring{\cite[#1]{#2}}{\myqcite{#1}{#2}}}
```

The image is a screenshot showing both the tex output and the bookmarks.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@bibitem}{\ignorespaces}{\label{bib-#1}\ignorespaces}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{[\ref{bib-#1}]}
\newcommand{\myqcite}[2]{[\ref{bib-#2}, #1]}
\newcommand{\mytcite}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\cite{#1}}{\mycite{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mytqcite}[2]{\texorpdfstring{\cite[#1]{#2}}{\myqcite{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section (\mytcite{author})}

\section{Section (\mytqcite{Section~2.1}{author})}

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{lib}

\end{document}
```

with `lib.bib`

```
@Article{author,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {J. Jour.},
  year =     2000,
  volume =   756,
  pages =    {1--77}
}
```

If your `bibitem`s also have option arguments, the you will need to patch `\@lbibitem` in the same way as above.

Comment: Thank you!!! I use now this command \subsection{Title \texorpdfstring{{\normalfont(\cite[Subsection~x.y]{author})}}{([\ref{bib-author}, Subsection~x.y])}} with the first displayed code you gave in the preamble. This works perfectly fine for me. I don't have problems with optional arguments in the pdfstring. With your solution, it even gives the right color for the hyperref, namely that of \cite and not that of \ref. Much better this way, than filling in the numbers manually when the document is finished.